# Trying to compare two csv files and write differences as output

Tags: python, csv, compare, difference

I'm developing a script which takes the difference between 2 csv files and makes a new csv file as output with the differences BUT only if the same 2 rows (refers to row number) between the two input files contain different data e.g. row 3 has "mike", "basketball player" in file 1 and row 3 in file 2 has "mike", "baseball player". The output csv would grab these print them and write them to a csv. It works but there are some issues (I know that this question has also been asked several times before but others have done it differently to me and since I'm fairly new to programming I don't quite understand their codes).

The output in the new csv file has each letter of the output in each cell (see image below) and I believe its something to do with the delimiter/quotechar/quoting line 37. I want them in their own cells without any fullstops, multiple spaces, commas or "|".

Another issue is that it takes a long time to run. I'm working with datasets of up to 50,000 rows and it can take over an hour to run. Why is this and what advice would be useful to speed it up? Put something outside of the for loop maybe? I did try the difflib method earlier on but I was only able to print the entire "input_file1" but not compare that file with another.

```
# aim of script is to compare csv files and output difference as a new csv

# import necessary libraries
import csv

# File1 = open(raw_input("path:"),"r") #filename, mode
# File2 = open(raw_input("path:"),"r") #filename, mode

# selects the 2 input files to be compared
input_file1 = "G:/savestuffhereqwerty/electorate_meshblocks/teststuff/Book1.csv"
input_file2 = "G:/savestuffhereqwerty/electorate_meshblocks/teststuff/Book2.csv"
# creates the blank output csv file
output_path = "G:/savestuffhereqwerty/electorate_meshblocks/outputs/output2.csv"
a = open(input_file1, "r")
output_file = open(output_path,"w")
output_file.close()
count = 0

with open(input_file1) as fp1:


    for row_number1, row_value1 in enumerate(fp1):
        if row_number1 == count:
            print "got to 1st point"
            value1 = row_value1

            with open(input_file2) as fp2:
                for row_number2, row_value2 in enumerate(fp2):
                    if row_number2 == count:
                        print "got to 2nd point"
                        value2 = row_value2

                        if value1 == value2:
                            print value1, value2
                        else:
                            print value1, value2
                            with open(output_path, 'wb') as f:
                                writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                                # testing to see if the code writes text to the csv
                                writer.writerow(["test1"])
                                writer.writerow(["test2", "test3", "test4"])
                                writer.writerows([value1, value2])
                                print "code reached writing stage"
        count += 1
        print count
print "done"
# replace(",",".")
```

[image: SCREENSHOT OF PRINTED OUTPUT]
[image: SCREENSHOT OF OUTPUT CSV]

Comment: You have a nested loop over 50000 rows. That is where the long running time is coming from. You do not have to compare every line from a with every line from b!

Comment: Is that because I have a for loop within a for loop? I don't know how to refer to input_file2 in the first for loop..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to compare the two files line-by-line, you should **not** loop through the second file for **every** line in the first file. You can simply [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) two csv readers and filter the rows:

```
input_file1 = "foo"
input_file2 = "bar"
output_path = "baz"

with open(input_file1) as fin1:
  with open(input_file2) as fin2:
    read1 = csv.reader(fin1)
    read2 = csv.reader(fin2)
    diff_rows = (row1 for row1, row2 in zip(read1, read2) if row1 != row2)
    with open(output_path, 'w') as fout:
      writer = csv.writer(fout)
      writer.writerows(diff_rows)
```

This solution assumes that the two files have the same number of lines.

Comment: Awesome thanks. My output gives me the different row but for input_file1. I'm trying to understand what you've written, what do I change so my output shows the different rows for input_file2? @schwobaseggl

Comment: @Crow132 You have probably found out by now. Replace `row1 for ...` by `row2 for ...`. This line is a [conditional generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions). This is one of the most handy features in Python. I think the syntax is fairly self-explanatory ;-)