# Comparing multiple columns of two csv files and save output as matching/not matching in new csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, comparison

Suppose i have Columns in file1.csv as

```
Customer id    Name 

Q1             Alen
W2             Ricky
E3             Katrina
R4             Anya
T5             Leonardo
```

and Columns in file2.csv as

```
Customer id    Name

Q1             Alen
W2             Harry
E3             Katrina
R4             Anya
T5             Leonard
```

here as you can see for Customer id: W2 the corresponding name is not matching. so the output.csv should be like below:

```
Customer id  Status

Q1           Matching
W2           Not matching
E3           Matching
R4           Matching
T5           Matching
```

How can i get the above output using python.

P.S. whats the code for comparing multiple columns, not just column Name?

My code

```
import csv
with open('file1.csv', 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile1:
    csvfile1_indices = dict((r[1], i) for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(csvfile1)))

with open('file2.csv', 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile2:
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as results:    
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile2)
        writer = csv.writer(results)

        writer.writerow(next(reader, []) + ['status'])

        for row in reader:
            index = csvfile1_indices.get(row[1])
            if index is not None:
                message = 'matching'
                writer.writerow(row + [message])

            else:
                 message = 'not matching'
                 writer.writerow(row + [message])

    results.close()
```

This is working fine, but can i write in any other easier way to get the same output? and what changes do i need to make to compare multiple columns?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How about just use string comparison tool like winmerge?

Comment: similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48693547/comparing-two-csv-files-and-get-the-difference-using-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41967523/trying-to-compare-two-csv-files-and-write-differences-as-output) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996033/python-compare-two-csv-files-and-print-out-differences)

Comment: @蕭為元  You can see the code i tried. I've edited the question

Comment: Can you use Pandas.?

Comment: @Sreeram yes, ofcourse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using Pandas, you can do it in 5 lines of code :

```py
import pandas as pd 

# assuming id columns are identical and contain the same values
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', index_col='Customer_id')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', index_col='Customer_id')

df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['status'], index=df1.index)
df3['status'] = (df1['Name'] == df2['Name']).replace([True, False], ['Matching', 'Not Matching'])

df3.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Edit : removed `sep = '\t'` to use default comma separator.

Comment: I got ValueError: Index Customer_id  invalid. but changing sep='\t' to sep=',' solved the error

Comment: Sorry my bad ! you can actually omit the separator argument altogether if you're using comma-separated values/

Answer (score 0):

Read both csv files into two different dictionaries and iterate over any of the dictionary and check for the same key in other. If you want order use OrderedDict

Comment: python script ? @Sanjay Idpuganti

Answer (score 0):

You can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on multiple columns:

```
f1
  Customer_id      Name
0          Q1      Alen
1          W2     Ricky
2          E3   Katrina
3          R4      Anya
4          T5  Leonardo

f2
  Customer_id      Name
0          Q1      Alen
1          W2     Harry
2          E3   Katrina
3          R4      Anya
4          T5  Leonardo

m = f1.merge(f2, on=['Customer_id', 'Name'], indicator='Status', how='outer')
  Customer_id      Name      Status
0          Q1      Alen        both
1          W2     Ricky   left_only
2          E3   Katrina        both
3          R4      Anya        both
4          T5  Leonardo        both
5          W2     Harry  right_only

m['Status'] = m['Status'].map({'both': 'Matching', 
                               'left_only': 'Not matching', 
                               'right_only': 'Not matching'})

m.drop_duplicates(subset=['Customer_id', 'Status'])
m.drop(['Name'], axis=1)
  Customer_id        Status
0          Q1      Matching
1          W2  Not matching
2          E3      Matching
3          R4      Matching
4          T5      Matching
```

Comment: @ Alex,  this will not result into the desired output , otherwise its easy :)

Comment: @pytorch I have updated the code a little bit to make it shorter/easier to maintain.